# How can a Javascript async function explicitly yield control at a specific point?

Tags: javascript, async-await

In a Javascript async function, is there a way to yield control to the event loop at a specific point in the code? For example:

```
async function example() {
    doSomeWork();
    ...  // Yield control to the event loop here
    doMoreWork();
}
```

I tried `await`ing a constant value or a resolved `Promise`, but that didn't seem to actually yield control.

Comment: Use `setTimeout()` and move the 'more work' into the timeout callback?

Comment: I love this simple syntax in the context of asynchronous coding. Callbacks change the scope of variables and the flow of the code, and so do Promises, which act like a chain of function calls instead of inline code. We need something better from our programming languages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I tried awaiting a constant value or a resolved Promise, but that didn't seem to actually yield control.

The reason that doesn't work is that after a promise resolves, the next code gets enqueued as a [microtask](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTML_DOM_API/Microtask_guide/In_depth). Microtasks run once the current synchronous stack of code finishes resolving, but *before* moving on to the next macro task in the event loop. So an await for a constant or resolved promise *will* yield to other synchronous code, but it will resume right after that, without advancing the event loop.

If you want to yield to the event loop, you'll need to use setTimeout or requestAnimationFrame. Be aware that setTimeout has a minimum amount of time, so even if you request 0 milliseconds, it will be at least 4ms.

```
async function example() {
  doSomeWork();
  await new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve));
  doMoreWork();
}
```

Comment: requestAnimationFrame has to be invoked twice, nested, to yield control, I believe.

Answer (score 2):

you can do something like

```
const yielder = () => new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(() => resolve(), 0))
```

then

```
await yielder();
```